# how to configure MAX11140 (ADC converter) With STM32F401RET? (SPI protocol)

Tags: spi, stm32f4discovery, adc, stm32f4

THIS IS THE LINK OF THE DATASHEET

https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/256/MAX11135-MAX11143-220131.pdf

HERE IS MY CODE

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  ** This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2019 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
uint16_t adc_config_reg=0b1000000000000100;
uint16_t unipolar_reg = 0b1000100000000000;
uint16_t bipolar_reg =  0b1001000000000000;
uint16_t adc_mode_reg = 0b0000100010000100;


uint16_t rx_adc_config_reg;
uint16_t rx_unipolar_reg;
uint16_t rx_bipolar_reg;
uint16_t rx_adc_mode_reg;

//uint16_t rx_adc_mode_reg1[16];
uint16_t rx[16];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&adc_config_reg,1,100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);



  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&rx_adc_config_reg,1,100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);
//
//      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
//
//    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&unipolar_reg,1,100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&rx_unipolar_reg,1,100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);


  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&bipolar_reg,1,100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&rx_bipolar_reg,1,100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&adc_mode_reg,1,100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);

//  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
//  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&rx_adc_mode_reg,1,100);
//  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&adc_mode_reg1,1,100);
//  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);
//
//  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
//  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&rx_adc_mode_reg,1,100);
//  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);




  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&rx_adc_mode_reg,1,100);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_6,GPIO_PIN_SET);


      HAL_Delay(2);
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_16;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog
        * Input
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB6 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I have configured With Cubmx

Data Size 16 bit 
CPOL=CPHA= 1
first bit = MSB

MY SPI COMMUNICATION IS COMPLETE 
I AM HAVING TROUBLE RECEIVING OUTPUT DATA AFTER CONVERSION

Comment: Can you be more specific what *having trouble receiving output data* means? Does the program crash? Does it return invalid data? If so, what data do you receive and what do you expect? And can you be more specific regarding the mode you want to operate MAX11140 in (internal/external clock, with/without FIFO etc.)?

Comment: as I turn on the echo I am supposed to get configuration data when I reset cs pin next and I am getting those data for ADC configuration register, unipolar register, and bipolar register but as I receive data after transmitting adc_mode_reg(as shown in code) I am getting unexpected output data and I am receiving it in loop and each time it varies and I am not getting any pattern of it and **My Vref is Hanging**  Currently I have selected Manual Mode in external Clock mode without FIFO as U can see in code (value of adc_mode_reg). actually I'm also not sure about **how do I select clock mode.**

Comment: @Codo I  am giving sck from my board(stm32f401 ret) and miso, mosi & ss. All grounds are common, giving power supply to IC from same board. when I ground my channel which I have selected It returns zero but when its hanging it returns different values each time. **I don't know if I am receiving in right way or there is another way to receive output data from IC** please help out I am getting frustrated now.

Comment: What do you mean by "My Vref is Hanging" and "when its hanging"? What have you connected to AIN1 and REF+? What's the voltage on these pins?

Comment: my **REF+ is 3.3v** and I have connected **2.5v supply to AIN1.**

Comment: Each SPI transaction transmits and receives data at the same time, even if you call `HAL_SPI_Receive()` or `HAL_SPI_Transmit()`. `HAL_SPI_Receive()` is likely to transmit `0xff` at the same time. Therefore, the ADC doesn't know anymore what to do. So in the main loop, try to change `HAL_SPI_Receive(...)` to `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive (&hspi1, &adc_mode_reg, &rx_adc_mode_reg, 1, 100);` That way the mode register is written at the same time as data is read and the ADC knows what to do next.

Comment: hooray **It Worked** Thank you so much brother I was missing that part. Btw as you can see I am rookie right now so, can you please guide me to clear these fundamentals about these protocols which can help me to get some advancements by providing some reference or guidance? It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Glad it works. I whish there was a good guide about SPI etc. but I don't know any...